While sending a AWS SQS message getting certification error using spring boot application
While sending a AWS SQS message getting below error

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX
path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target

AWS SQS write and read message using spring boot application
